# Calculus: Differentiable Function and Tangent Line

Tags: calculus, self-learning

I am not sure how to approach this question:

> Let $f(x)$ be a continuous and differentiable function of order 2. Let $f ''(x)>0$ for all values of $x$. The tangent line to the function at $x=1$ is $y=-x+1$. Show that $f(1.1)>-0.1$.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By doing a second derivative test, We could conclude that $f(x)$ is concave upward since $f''(x)>0$. The only intersection between the tangent line $y=-x+1$ and $f(x)$ should be at $x=1$. And since $f(x)$ is concave upward, the tangent line must lie below $f(x)$ everywhere except at $x=1$.

The y value of the tangent line at $x=1.1$ is $y=-1.1+1=-0.1$. Since $f(x)$ is above that line, $f(1.1)>-0.1$ for sure.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't understand. If f(x) is concave upward, and it "touches" the line at x=1, why does it has to intersect it at x=-1? I am not sure where -1 came from.

Comment: @user2899944 sorry that would be a typo. It should be 1 instead of -1.

Comment: OK, then I do understand ! :-)

Answer (score 0):

By approximatin f(x) by using two of terms of its Taylor series you can determine the equation of the tangent line as:
\begin{equation}
y=f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0)
\end{equation}
where $x_0=1$. Then since
\begin{equation}
f(1)+f'(1)(x-1)= -x+1
\end{equation}
we can conclude that $f(1)=0$ and $f'(1)=-1$. When consider the term of order two in the taylor expansion, since $f''(x)$ is always positive, we can conclude that
\begin{equation}
f(1.1)=f(1)+f'(1)(1.1-1)+ a positive term
\end{equation}
Then $f(1.1)=-0.1$ + a positive term